# how to pass a 2d array of ints between activities?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I am trying to pass a 2d array of ints to nextactivity. i tried to use bundle.putSerializable(like sending a string array) but i got null pointer exception. Any ideas??

here is my code. 
(tosend)

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,activityvogel.class);
                    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                    mBundle.putSerializable("cost",cost);
                    myIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
                    startActivity(myIntent);}
```

(toreceive)

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int cost[][]= (int[][]) extras.getSerializable("cost");
```

Comment: There's a size limit on what you can pass through an intent. How large is the array you're passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Convert int 2D array to String 2D array and send it just like you did**

To convert: you would have to do so manually with a two-layer 
`for()` loop:

```
String[][] converted = new String[cost.length][];
for(int index = 0; index < cost.length; index++) {
    converted[index] = new String[cost[index].length];
    for(int subIndex = 0; subIndex < cost[index].length; subIndex++){
        converted[index][subIndex] = Integer.toString(cost[index][subIndex]);
    }
}
```

To send:

```
mBundle .putSerializable("cost", converted);
```

To get:

```
String[][] converted = (String[][]) mBundle.getSerializable("cost");
```

And then again convert it into int 2D array.

String[][] extends Object, while int and int[][] do not

Comment: Already converted here , when casting 
String[][] value = (String[][]) mBundle .getSerializable("cost");

Comment: i mean how to convert int array cost(2d)  to a string array cost (2d)?

Comment: i tried your answer but i still get a null pointer exception. i tried to print the converted array to see the values before the intent and everything was ok . any other suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for get data:

```
String[][] strCost = null;
Object[] objCost = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("cost");
if (objCost != null){
    strCost = new String[objCost.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < objCost.length; i++){
        strCost[i] = (String[]) objCost[i];
    }
}
```

Then turn back into `int` ...